# How can I do to reduce the height of my map using leaflet?

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, tailwind-css

I am using this code :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import './styles.css';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    center: [51.505, -0.091],
    zoom: 13,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Map center={this.state.center} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
          <Marker position={this.state.center}>
            <Popup>
              A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
            </Popup>
          </Marker>
        </Map>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

But I try to reduce the height and I don't achieve using Tailwind CSS. I tried that :

```
<Map className="h-0" center={this.state.center} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
          <TileLayer
            attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
          />
          <Marker position={this.state.center}>
            <Popup>
              A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
            </Popup>
          </Marker>
        </Map>
```

ie `className="h-0"` in the tag Map but it does not work.

Could you help me please ?

Thank you !

Here is my code without tailwind css

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-s1q44

Answer (score 1):

The referenced `styles.css` defines the dimensions of the map:

```css
.leaflet-container {
  height: 600px; /* <-- map height */
  width: 100%;
}
```

You can reduce the map height by decreasing the height from `600px` to e.g. `400px`.

If you would like to use Tailwind, I would recommend replacing the styles defined in `styles.css` with Tailwind equivalent classes. Removing the `styles.css` import and defining a height by using a Tailwind classes on the `Map` component works as well.

```js
<Map className='h-36' center={this.state.center} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
  // map component content
</Map>
```